# Vector Questions

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

So I have two questions, first of all, would a value of one divided by a magnitude of $v$ multiplied by the vector $w$ be simply an example of scalar multiplication or would it be undefined? Same goes for one divided by a vector multiplied by a magnitude.
My guess is that you cannot have one divided by a vector in the first place so I believe it’s undefined am I correct?

Comment: Your first example is perfectly well-defined. Your second would not be, because vector division is not defined, in general.

Comment: Alright that’s what I was thinking that it would be defined as scalar multiplication of a vector  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- A value of one divided by a magnitude of $v$ multiplied by the vector $w$ means

$$\frac1{\|v\|}w.$$

It is well defined as long as $v \ne 0$. Note that $\frac1{\|v\|}$ is a scalar here.

- One divided by a vector is not defined.